# Gradle RootProject from Remote Artifactory

Tags: gradle

I have a `commons` library that I'd like to use as a `rootProject`. This commons library is published to my `company nexus artifactory`.

Now, inside `subproject` I created a `settings.gradle` file with the following content:

```
rootProject.name = 'commons'
include = 'project-a'
```

But `commons` is a project from nexus, it isn't locally in my filesystem. Is this possible in gradle ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you wanna use the `commons` library as a root project?

Comment: Exactly @romtsn, I wanna use `commons` as root because I need to keep default dependencies in all my projects.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not getting it, what default dependencies are you talking about? I think Your question needs a bit more info

Comment: I have a `commons project` with a `build.gradle` with many dependencies. I wanna reuse this `build.gradle` file in multiple projects to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: Why not switch to [version catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:version-catalog-plugin) and share it across the projects?

Comment: I never used `version catalogs` but I will try and return here, thanks.